# going from amazon s3 to cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I've been using amazon s3 to serve a large number of images. I've decided to use cloudfront. Would s3 links now intelligently use the cdn or would I have to change all my urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires a change:

1. If you have been loading your images from the same domain provided by S3.
2. If you had used an alias like "images.example.com" which was pointing to your S3 bucket, then you need not worry about it, since, you can create a cloud-front for your bucket and then point the cname to the newly created cloud-front URL.